# Create AWS lambda event source to trigger file create by aws cli cp command

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to create a AWS lambda event source to catch the action of upload a file via aws cli cp command, but it couldn't be triggered when i upload a file. Here is what i have done:

**I configured the event source as following**:
[image]

I have tried all the four option of Object Created event type, it just didn't work.

**I use the aws cli as following**:

```
aws s3 cp sample.html s3://ml.hengwei.me/data/
```

*Is there anywhere i miss configured?*

Comment: Did you specify a prefix or suffix?

Comment: lobo@, yes, i did. It worked with suggestion of jarmod@. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering your Lambda from the wrong event type.

Using the awscli to cp files up into S3 does not cause an s3:ObjectCreated:Copy event (which I believe relates to an S3 copy operation, copying an object from one bucket to another). In your case, the object is being uploaded to S3 and I presume that it results in either s3:ObjectCreated:Put or s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload.

The events include:

- s3:ObjectCreated:Put – An object was created by an HTTP PUT
  operation.
- s3:ObjectCreated:Post – An object was created by HTTP POST
  operation.
- s3:ObjectCreated:Copy – An object was created an S3 copy
  operation.
- s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload – An object was
  created by the completion of a S3 multi-part upload.
- s3:ObjectCreated:* – An object was created by one of the event types
  listed above or by a similar object creation event added in the
  future.

Full list of events is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types). Note that the awscli may or may not use multi-part upload so you need to handle both situations.

Comment: jarmod@, I used the Object Created(All) option, it worked!  Thanks a lot!